# Not able to find JWebPane in jdk 7

Tags: java, java-7

i wanted to use java Browser component that is suppose to be there in jdk 7 (javax.net package ) by class **JWebPane** but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JWebPane was supposed to be included in Java 7, but it ended up as javafx.scene.web.WebView in JavaFX 2.0. Since 1.7_06 JavaFX 2.0 is part of the jre-release, but when using eclipse you have to explicitly include the jar on the build path since eclipse doesn't include it in the runtime library.

Comment: Where this jar file can be downloaded from?

Comment: @pravin How do I explicitly add the jar to the build path? I need to use JWebPane in an Eclipse project but cannot get it to work. I suppose that this is why.